# laravel 5.2 will freak out if table exists when running migrations

Tags: php, migration, laravel-5

I need a work around or a check to see if the table exists.

Situation:

I have a test site and a production site, on the test site I created and ran a task that over time created 25million records. these records were then exported from the test database and imported into the production so I don't have to re-run the task over again.

this allowed me to switch out some the logic to now say, do the same fetch but check to make sure the record doesn't already exist, vastly increeasing the speed of this whole task (the task spawns about 125 ish jobs that do 100 fetches split up into 18 concurrent connections) So this takes a while.

Because of this on production the migration  will be like "uh this table exists ... sorry crash time"

So I want to say "if table exists ignore the migration, else run the migration for create"

**ideas?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#writing-migrations), specifically, where it describes "Checking For Table / Column Existence":

```
if (Schema::hasTable('users')) {
    //
}
```

Comment: `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' does not have a method 'hasTable'`  i am using laravel 5.2